# Multiple Custom Form Plugins for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm relatively new to WordPress and PHP, however I am trying to create my own shortcode plugin, which I have completed and is working.

However if I add more than 1 on the same page in WP, both forms submit and are not exclusive of each other.

I have search around the web, but can't find out how to easily separate the form id's, below is my plugin code:

```
function wptuts_contact_form_sc($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    //"email" => get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
    "id" => '',
    "attachment" => '',
    "desc" => '',
    "subject" => '',
    "label_email" => 'Your E-mail Address',
    "label_submit" => 'Submit',
    "error_empty" => 'Please fill in all the required fields.',
    "error_noemail" => 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.',
    "success" => 'Thanks, your voucher has been sent to '
), $atts));

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $error = false;
    $required_fields = array("email");

    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $form_data[$field] = strip_tags($value);
    }

    foreach ($required_fields as $required_field) {
        $value = trim($form_data[$required_field]);
        if(empty($value)) {
            $error = true;
            $result = $error_empty;
        }
    }

    if(!is_email($form_data['email'])) {
        $error = true;
        $result = $error_noemail;
    }

    if ($error == false) {
        $email_subject = "Eurest Voucher - " . $desc;
        $email_message = "Hi, Your requested voucher/offer is attached to this email.";
        $headers  = "From: Eurest Vouchers <Vouchers@eurestfood.com>\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
        $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . $attachment);
        $email = $form_data['email'];
        wp_mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, $attachments);
        $result = $success . $form_data['email'];
        $sent = true;
    }
}

if($result != "") {
    $info = '<div class="info">'.$result.'</div>';
}
$email_form = '<form class="contact-form" method="post" id="'.$id.'" action="'.get_permalink().'">
    <div>
        <label for="cf_email">'.$label_email.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="cf_email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['email'].'" /><input type="submit" value="'.$label_submit.'" name="send" id="cf_send" />
    </div>
</form>';

if($sent == true) {
    return $info;
} else {
    return $info.$email_form;
}
} add_shortcode('emailattachment', 'wptuts_contact_form_sc');
```

If someone can help that would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you've forgotten the last attribute in the function shortcode_atts, even if it's optionnal, you need to call it.
Also, is there some code missing ?

edit : you need to id your forms otherwise the function will pick up the datas twice. call the second shortcode giving the value 'second' to teh variable $num_f like so [wptuts_contact_form_sc -your bunch of vars here- num_f="second"]

```
function wptuts_contact_form_sc($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    //"email" => get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
    "id" => '',
    "attachment" => '',
    "desc" => '',
    "subject" => '',
    "label_email" => 'Your E-mail Address',
    "label_submit" => 'Submit',
    "error_empty" => 'Please fill in all the required fields.',
    "error_noemail" => 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.',
    "success" => 'Thanks, your voucher has been sent to ',
    "num_f" => 'first'
    ), $atts));

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $num_f == 'second') {
    $error = false;
    $required_fields = array("email");

    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $form_data[$field] = strip_tags($value);
    }

    foreach ($required_fields as $required_field) {
        $value = trim($form_data[$required_field]);
        if(empty($value)) {
            $error = true;
            $result = $error_empty;
        }
    }

    if(!is_email($form_data['email'])) {
        $error = true;
        $result = $error_noemail;
    }

    if ($error == false) {
        $email_subject = "Eurest Voucher - " . $desc;
        $email_message = "Hi, Your requested voucher/offer is attached to this email.";
        $headers  = "From: Eurest Vouchers <Vouchers@eurestfood.com>\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
        $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . $attachment);
        $email = $form_data['email'];
        wp_mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, $attachments);
        $result = $success . $form_data['email'];
        $sent = true;
    }
}

if($result != "") {
    $info = '<div class="info">'.$result.'</div>';
}
$email_form = '<form class="contact-form" method="post" id="'.$id.'" action="'.get_permalink().'">
    <div>
        <label for="cf_email">'.$label_email.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="cf_email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['email'].'" /><input type="submit" value="'.$label_submit.'" name="send" id="cf_send" />
    </div>
</form>';

if($sent == true) {
    return $info;
} else {
    return $info.$email_form;
}
} add_shortcode('emailattachment', 'wptuts_contact_form_sc');
```

To have more than two forms, you can either do it manually by calling the third block 'trird' and so on, but that's not very good practice to be honest...

If I were you I would change your code at the core, create a function that would return the form with a hidden field like so : `<input type"hidden" name="hidden" value=" . $nf . ">` and then instead of controling `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, you'd control the value of $_POST['n'] after checking if it's set ofc.

Here's the code I came up with :

```
<?php

function wptuts_contact_form_sc($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    //"email" => get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
    "id" => '',
    "attachment" => '',
    "desc" => '',
    "subject" => '',
    "label_email" => 'Your E-mail Address',
    "label_submit" => 'Submit',
    "error_empty" => 'Please fill in all the required fields.',
    "error_noemail" => 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.',
    "success" => 'Thanks, your voucher has been sent to ',
    "nf" => '1'
), $atts));

if (isset($_POST['hidden'])) {
    $hidden = $_POST['hidden'];
    $error = false;
    $required_fields = array("email");

    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $form_data[$field] = strip_tags($value);
    }

    foreach ($required_fields as $required_field) {
        $value = trim($form_data[$required_field]);
        if(empty($value)) {
            $error = true;
            $result = $error_empty;
        }
    }

    if(!is_email($form_data['email'])) {
        $error = true;
        $result = $error_noemail;
    }

    if ($error == false) {
        $email_subject = "Eurest Voucher - " . $desc;
        $email_message = "Hi, Your requested voucher/offer is attached to this email.";
        $headers  = "From: Eurest Vouchers <Vouchers@eurestfood.com>\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
        $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . $attachment);
        $email = $form_data['email'];
        wp_mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, $attachments);
        $result = $success . $form_data['email'];
        $sent = true;
    }
} else {
$hidden = $_POST['hidden'];
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $nf; $i++) {
if($result != "" && $i == $hidden) {
    $info = '<div class="info">'.$result.'</div>';
}
$email_form = '<form class="contact-form" method="post" id="'.$id.'" action="'.get_permalink().'">
    <div>
        <label for="cf_email">'.$label_email.':</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="' . $nf . '"> 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="cf_email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['email'].'" /><input type="submit" value="'.$label_submit.'" name="send" id="cf_send" />
    </div>
</form>';

if($sent == true) {
    return $info;
} else {
    return $info . $email_form;
}
}
} add_shortcode('emailattachment', 'wptuts_contact_form_sc');

?>
```

Let me know if it works, (or does not) I obviously couldnt test it so there might be somehting wrong, in which case I just hope you got the whole idea behind it.

Comment: $shortcode
(string) (optional) Shortcode name to be used by shortcode_atts_{$shortcode} - Even if this parameter is optional, do not(!) avoid it. Else it will be impossible for plugins to target this shortcode for pre-processing.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this PHP stuff... what do I need to add to make this work correctly?

Comment: Well, to be honest I think you're using the shortcode the wrong way in the first place, so thats gonna be pretty hard for me to sort it out for you. What's the website you're using it on ? Are you calling twice the same shortcode ? give me somethign to work on :)

Comment: Yeah I am using it twice on the same page, which is why there is a problem, as both forms submit!

Other than the fact both submit, it works great!

Here is the site: http://bentley-live.bespokexl.co.uk/deals-voucher-codes/

Comment: Ive edited my post above. have a try like that, let me knwo if it works. I have never used shortcode_atts() so my solution si only made on what ive read on the wordpress codex, hoping it works.

Comment: So...Steve, is it working ? Can you mark my answer as the correct one if it's working pretty please ?

Comment: Hi, No worries I will. I can't test until tomorrow as I have had to leave my laptop at work whilst they migrate it to another domain.

I understand what you have done, however how can I make this work for more than 2 shortcodes etc... as I may have 5/6 to a page.

Comment: I started writing a reply here but it's way to long, i'll edit my answer above later on tonight, it might take me some time.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate the help... I'm normally a ASP.NET coder!
However I am seeing a lot of benefits with PHP - there are so many built in functions!

Comment: Yes PHP is pretty nice :) I am hotel manager, i'm not coding for a living although i like it a lot !
Anyway I hope this has been helpful, let me knwo if you have any further questions concerning this code, I love to helpw hen I can !

Comment: Hey, sorry its taken a while to reply! I have added the code to the site, however from what I can see it is still causing both controls to post - as I get 2 emails instead of 1 and the page updates to say thankyou on both offers.

Feel free to play: http://bentley-live.bespokexl.co.uk/deals-voucher-codes/

Comment: Dear ho dear....that's gonne be an entertaining case to solve. Anyway you could share your entire plugin with me ?

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that the variable $nf has to be set in the shortcode, $nf represent the number of identical blocks you want to display, and note that you only need one shortcode. Can you try again and let me know please.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code above, but its still the same. Here is the plugin http://bentley-live.bespokexl.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/email-form/emailform.php

Comment: I can't download a plugin straigth from a server mate... send it to bibispamz[at]gmail[dot]com, Ill have a look at it and get back to you here